# Loading Json File in Spark 2.2.0 with Scala DataFrame gives _corrupt_record column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

While loading Json Data in to DataFrame I get only `_corrupt_record` column.I tried Below both options but same problem exists,please guide.

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("<file>")

val df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("file.json").values)
```

Comment: Could you put a sample json which gives you the issues? Please try to create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did this answer help? Or was there a corruption in the file?